# Adding the ip to the filter of tcpdump

Tags: tcpdump

I use this tcpdump command to HTTP GET filtering :

```
tcpdump -s 0 -A 'tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x47455420'
```

How can add IP address to this filter?

Comment: tcpdump -s 0 -A "tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x47455420 and host X.X.X.X"

Comment: @Idance . Thanks I`ll post it as an answer, so we can consider this question answered.

Answer (score 3):

You can add on multiple filters like this:

```
tcpdump -s 0 -A "tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x47455420 and host X.X.X.X"
```

You can also specify whether you want to filter based on the source or destination hosts or ports like this:

```
tcpdump -s 0 -A "tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x47455420 and dst host X.X.X.X and (dst port YYY or dst port ZZZ)"
```